Classifying bounded linear functions satisfying convolution identity

Find all bounded linear functionals $T$ on $Y= \{f \in W^{1,1}[0,1]: f(0)=0\}$ such that there exists $K>0$ such that $$\int_0^1|Tf(\cdot-t)|\ dt\le K  \|f\|_1\qquad \forall\ f\in Y\tag{1}$$

My attempt: Since $T\in Y'$, there exists $g_1,g_2\in L^\infty[0,1]$ such that
$$Tf=\langle g_1,f\rangle+\langle g_2,f'\rangle=\int_0^1 (g_1f+g_2f')\qquad \forall\ f\in Y.$$ Plugging in (1), we get
$$f\star g_1+f'\star g_2 \in L^1(0,1)\qquad \forall\ f\in Y;$$ where $\star$ denotes convolution.
My questions: What can I say about $g_1$ and $g_2$ now, so I'm able to classify all $T$ satisfying (1)?

What does $f(\cdot - t)$ mean? This is not generally defined on all of $[0,1]$ for $f \in Y$. Also, it will definitely in general not be contained in Y, even if one adopts the convention of extending functions in Y by zero to the negative reals.

@PhoemueX $f(\cdot-t)$ means that $f(s-t)=0$ whenever $s-t\notin [0,1]$. Also, as mentioned $T$ is a bounded linear functional on $Y$, so it maps $Tf$ is a scalar.
